# How to get a single item from an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I can do:

```
std::unordered_set<MyThing*> things;
MyThing aThing = nullptr; 
for(auto item : mySet){
    aThing = item;
    break;
}
```

Is there a way to get a single item without having to write all this code to iterate ?

I want to know simply out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MyThing* aThing = things.empty() ? nullptr : *things.begin();
```

Comment: Why do you add an "*" before things.begin() ?

Comment: Because `things.begin()` is an iterator. To get the object it points to, you need to dereference it.